# Excel: can offset use a corresponding code as a value in another column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

First off, I've tried to do my research, but I'm so inexperienced I don't know what I don't know, and I don't know how to ask the right question. I'd imagine my whole issue is just not understanding the functionality of excel.

I'll start by explaining my story and goals - I'm open to trying a more efficient method!

TL;DR - I need to create some sort of column search function that offsets a value

**My Story:**
So, I am about to launch an online personal training business. One of my services is nutrition coaching, and I'll be creating weekly meal plans for clients. To create these meal plans I want to be able to create a 'preset meal' button that I can easily press to add a given preset to the meal plan. I've been operating inefficiently, where I manually enter the quantity of each ingredient each time. I have tables for the different food groups (meat, grains, dairy, fruit, veg, other), they will be set up like the following. In this example, one of the required ingredients is 2 slices of ham (see Column F);

This is the previously set up macro, it was selecting a given Cell, not finding the ingredient and inputing a value from an offset
[image: screen of the code]

Example of table now
[image: Example of table now]

**Column A** - *Ingredient* - e.g;

Meat Table;'pork_ham_slice'

**Column B** - *Energy (kj)* - e.g;

Meat Table;'460'

**Column C:E** - *Carbs(g)|Protein(g)|Fat(g)* - e.g;

Meat Table;'7'|'15'|'2.5'

**Column F** - *Quantity* - e.g; -

Meat Table;'***2***'

**Column G** - *Energy (kj)**x Column F*** - e.g;

Meat Table;'920'

**Column H:J** - *[Carbs(g)|Protein(g)|Fat(g)]**x Column F*** - e.g;

Meat Table;'14'|'30'|'5'

**My Goal:** I want to be able to create a button/macro that will search **Column A** for the given ingredient, before inputing a value into **Column F**. I had started creating a few buttons where they input values into a specific Cell in **Column A**, however, I will continually be adding more ingredients, and I want the **Column A** to be sorted alphabetically, which instantly throws off this set cell method as I add a new ingredient.

At the end of the day, I thought some combination of VLOOKUP and OFFSET could be used, but I just can't figure this one out - Youtube isn't enough, and here we are.

If any of this was unclear, I'm more than happy to provide further details!

Guy

Comment: Please show us your work sor far and your exact table structure - screenshots would be very helpful.

Comment: Please always include the code in your question and format it as code block. [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: You will find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) very helpful in terms of speeding up your code by avoiding .Select.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an example how to find a specific value in a table:

```
Dim FoundIngredient As Range
Set FoundIngredient = Worksheets("MeatTable").Range("A:A").Find(What:="Pork_Ham_Slice", LookAt:=xlWhole)

If FoundIngredient Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "ingredient not found"
    Exit Sub
Else
    FoundIngredient.Offset(ColumnOffset:=5).Value = 2
End If
```